# Windows Store App binding a control to two properties

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-store-apps

I saw several questions about `binding` a control to two `properties` in `wpf` .
Is it possible to do that in `windows store apps`?
I habe a `combobox` and want to fill it with a value that will be calculated by using two properties and a `converter`.
Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: So, in WPF this is called `Multibinding`, and is unfortunately not available in stock WinRT. You could try checking to see if there are any third-party libraries on CodePlex that give this functionality. You may also want to look into the many `Behaviors` libraries. I believe one of them could assist you in doing something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Nate Diamond. A third-party library could be a solution, that's true.
As a workaround, I created a new property in my viewmodel and binded to that one which is maybe not a very nice solution.
Thanks for you upvote. =)